# PhpMyAdmin data import performance issues

Tags: mysql, performance, phpmyadmin, file-import

Originally, my question was related to the fact that PhpMyAdmin's SQL section wasn't working properly. As suggested in the comments, I realized that it was the amount of the input is impossible to handle. However, this didn't provide me with a valid solution of how to deal with the files that have (in my case - 35 thousand record lines) in format of (CSV):

```
...
20120509,126,1590.6,0
20120509,127,1590.7,1
20120509,129,1590.7,6
...
```

The Import option in PhpMyadmin is struggling just as the basic copy-paste input in SQL section does. This time, same as previously, it takes 5 minutes until the max execution time is called and then it stops. What is interesting tho, it adds like 6-7 thousand of records into the table. So that means the input actually goes through and does that almost successfully. I also tried halving the amount of data in the file. Nothing has changed however.

There is clearly something wrong now. It is pretty annoying to have to play with the data in php script when simple data import is not work.

Comment: militant retaggers are militant ;)

Comment: Are you sure it's uploading to run?  It sounds like it's just too large of input for the web interface to upload to the server.  Why not just execute from PHP?

Comment: Hmm, now I feel quite dumb asking this question. But I recall having issues adding data from a file. Need to test this and update or remove answer if needed. Thanks for pointing obvious things.

Comment: Updated the question in general to point out the key problem. The original question was just a scratch of the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your php upload max size.

Do you know where your php.ini file is?

First of all, try putting this file into your web root:

```
phpinfo.php
```

( see http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php )

containing:

```
<?php

phpinfo();

?>
```

Then navigate to http://www.yoursite.com/phpinfo.php

Look for "php.ini".

To upload large files you need max_execution_time, post_max_size, upload_max_filesize

Also, do you know where your error.log file is? It would hopefully give you a clue as to what is going wrong.

EDIT:

Here is the query I use for the file import:

```
$query = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$file_name' INTO TABLE `$table_name` FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY
    ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '$nl'";
```

Where $file_name is the temporary filename from php global variable $_FILES, $table_name is the table already prepared for import, and $nl is a variable for the csv line endings (default to windows line endings but I have an option to select linux line endings).

The other thing is that the table ($table_name) in my script is prepared in advance by first scanning the csv to determine column types. After it determines appropriate column types, it creates the MySQL table to receive the data.

I suggest you try creating the MySQL table definition first, to match what's in the file (data types, character lengths, etc). Then try the above query and see how fast it runs. I don't know how much of a factor the MySQL table definition is on speed.

Also, I have no indexes defined in the table until AFTER the data is loaded. Indexes slow down data loading.

Comment: When I execute some query from php script, 10k records are inserted immediately. I tested and it was adding ~18k records per second. However, it wasn't able to handle very large queries (throwing error: mysql server has gone away), so I separated into parts of 10k records to insert and it was doing perfectly fine. When I try to import from CVS/Excel file using PhpMyAdmin, the script is doing something (not sure how to check what exactly) and after 5 minutes it stops reaching max execution time. I find that it added 6-7k rows into the database.

Comment: What I can tell is: it must reach the state of data insertion, but is unable to finish it. I am guessing that the plugins to upload anything but SQL (again, in chunks of 10k or so, but not more) aren't suitable for large chunks of data, but again, that is unlikely. Upload max file size isn't an issue, the files are way lower than it. About post_max_size: wouldn't it just halt the process if it was too big? And in general, what is taking 5 minutes? Why doesn't it throw an error saying some variable is exceeded? 10k records in 5 minutes is ridiculous :(

Comment: I am thinking as it is trying to add all data into one query (same as I tried, but got instant error and thus reduced it to 10k each) and thus struggles with that, but I find it really weird that the creators of such a huge scale project wouldn't have thought about uploading large files and not separated them into smaller queries.

Comment: I'm testing my current PHP/MySQL program with csv files above 2 megabytes. Actually I think I even had one that was 5 or 10 MB. Are you trying to just load all the data into one table? If so, "LOAD DATA INFILE" is the method you should use. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html
I use that to put the data into a "raw" table. Then I do further processing from there.

Comment: Well I am using what I am offered by PhpMyAdmin and that is clearly not working properly. I can easily use some self written php script to upload all the data (and I think that this will be a solution). However, it is just a slight inconvenience, however it is very annoying that PhpMyAdmin has bugs which HAD to be fixed before release.

Comment: Part of the reason I wrote my own script was because I was having endless problems with phpMyAdmin myself. With my script I can import 10k rows in 0.008 seconds.

Comment: Would you mind sharing your script just for some ideas how you make it that fast? Because when I was testing, I was getting way lower speed. Also, add one line of the input file just to know how to data looks exactly. Thanks a lot in advance :)

Comment: Ok, I added the query from my script to the bottom of my answer. It is a simple LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE.

Comment: Aaaah, now I get the point! Huge effort from you, trying to help me, is highly appreciated.