# Parse CSV and import to PHP is slow

Tags: php, mysql

I have a csv file looks like this

```
col1, col2, col3
1 ,  John, ABC
```

I need to parse `ABC` in column 3 into `A,B,C` because the new relation needs `col1, col3 (each letter)`.

`$j` is the row, and `$i` is the column.

```
$j = 0;  
while (($row = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ',')) !== false) {
    $i = 0;
    $id = 0;
    foreach ($row as $field) {
        # save the id of each row
        if($j >0 && $i == 0){
            $id = $field;
        }

        # parse the third column for non-header rows)
        if($j > 0 && $i >= 3){
            $char_array = str_split($field);
            foreach($char_array as $value){
                //echo $value;
                //echo $id.$value."<br/>";
                mysql_query("INSERT INTO sample VALUES('".$id."', '".$value."')");
            }
        }
        $i = $i + 1;  # increment the column
    }
    $j = $j +1;   # move to the next row
}
```

1. This is slow. I have more than 720 rows, and most of them have more than 5 characters in the third column. `ABCDE`, so on average we have 720 x 5. That's a huge number.
   I get `timeout`. I can change the max time for execution locally, but I need to run this on my student linux account. I don't have that kind of privilege.
2. I suspect because of timeout (it didn't say it this time), I have up `id = 502`. I am missing the rest (I have up to 720 rows).

What can I do? I am only interested in the first and third column.

Comment: why not use php's built in csv functions ? fgetcsv(), str_getcsv()

Comment: You mean `LOAD DATA`? or `fgetcsv`? I need to parse them? I thought it would be difficult to parse.

Comment: @Dagon I have `fgetcsv`. That;s how I read the csv file.

Comment: your code indentation was displayed badly because you'd mixed spaces and tabs. I've fixed it up for you to make the code more readable in the question.

Comment: my bad dident see that, i wouldn't run one query for each row, but build it so you just run  one  query in total.

Comment: Be careful Dagon. Too long query could be as inefficient as many short ones. Give a try to look at my question. The picked answer has some useful ideas. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10568664/phpmyadmin-data-import-performance-issues

Comment: $j = $j + 1 will slow you down a bit. Use $j++

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IO disk read/write is slow too. But it doesn't timeout and with cache you are not going to perform that bad actually. In fact, I've done this all the time, with data of size larger than 20MB in PHP. Not that bad.... If I really want to do big data, I'd use Python, C++ algorithms because I have them ready anyway.

Example, based on your code (might contain errors):

```
$big = array(); 
$j = 0;
$k = 0;

while(....) {

    ....
    foreach($char_array as $value){
        #mysql_query("INSERT INTO sample VALUES('".$id."', '".$value."')");
        $big[$k][0] = $id;
        $big[$k][1] = $value;
        $k = $k+1;
    }

  ....
}
```

Here you make a nested array. `$big` is the outer array, and inside you assign the column and row.

Use `fputcsv` to write into a new csv. The new csv, according to your specification, should looks like this:

> 1, A
>
> 1, B

and here is the code to write into csv (from php doc)

```
$fp = fopen('new.csv', 'w');

foreach ($big as $fields) {
    fputcsv($fp, $fields);
}
fclose($fp);

}
```

now you can load csv into db.

---

EDIT.
I just tried with 720 rows with data like this and copy and paste 720 times.

```
1, ABCDEFGHIJK
```

Didn't take that long... maybe 1-2 seconds.

Comment: What is 720 rows? That's child play! I'm loading up a csv file with 1MM+ records. Now that's a true stress tester.

Answer (score 1):

[Untested]

```
$query = '';
$array = array();

if (($handle = fopen("file.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($row = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ',')) !== false) {
        //$total = count($row);

        foreach ($row as $key=>$value) {
           $chrs = str_split($value[2]);
           foreach ($chrs as $chr){
               $array[] = {$value[0], $chr} ;
           }   
        }        
    }
}

foreach ($array as $key=>$value){
    $query .= 'INSERT INTO table VALUES ('.$value[0].', "'.$value[1].'")'; 
}
if ($query <> ''){
    mysql_query($query, $connection);
}
```

Comment: @tftd: Sorry.. Thought no one's interested on this.

Comment: Is it more efficient to load the query like this, or generate a csv, and then dump it into the db using `LOAD` ? Just curious.

Comment: @CppLearner: Not too sure. At least, script won't need any file/disk operation this way.

Comment: an sql query has a max length(configurable). This type of code that doesnt chunk at all is bound to fail on large files, if you don't first hit memory limits.