# PHP random early ending of script

Tags: php, exit

Long time reader, first time poster

I have a script which imports rows from a CSV file, processes in, then inserts into a MYSQL database, the CSV file itself has around 18,800 rows.

This script runs as part of a WordPress plugin installation, and appears to be very temperamental. Sometimes it will complete the entire script and load the page as normal, other times, lets say, 2/3s of the time, it will only import around 17.5k of the rows before silently terminating the script and reloading the page without any GET or POST vars,

I have tried everything I can think of to see why its doing it, but with no luck.

The server software is Apache installed on Linux, 
The Server error log doesn't have any entries, 
max execution time is set to 0, 
PHP max input time is 1800, 
PHP register long arrays is set to on,
The script is running as PHP 5.3.5CGI 
The database is hosted on the same server 
The max memory limit is 256M
The max post size is 7M

Is there anything I am missing that may be causing an error?

Any help would be appreciated, as I am totally stumped!

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
If I use a CSV file of 15k rows instead of 18k it completes correctly, could it be a time issue?

Comment: turn on error reporting or check error.log see if you can find anything

Comment: Drop some debug `echo` statements in there at critical points, see where the failure is. Also, try using keepalive connections in case your browser is deciding to cut the connection.

Comment: @slash197 Error reporting is on, no entries in log, or on screen

Comment: have you checked if there are any mysql processes hanging?

Comment: @Polynomial the error is happening somewhere inside the 18k loop, I will try it again with the keepalive headers and see what happens

Comment: @KasiaGogolek There appears to be no processes hanging by looking at the Show Processlist, its just showing 2, one is sleeping, the other is showing the process list

Comment: @Polynomial The keepalive headers didn't work either

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10568664/phpmyadmin-data-import-performance-issues Maybe it will help :)

Comment: @AndriusNaruševičius We cannot directly insert the CSV as its an export from another site, so we need to chop and re-format columns first also no errors are thrown from mysql as mentioned in your question, it is similar though although the answer doesn't apply to this :(

Comment: "without any GET or POST vars" and you are limiting it with "The max post size is 7M". Can there be a relation by any chance? Have you tried increasing it to lets say 70M. Anything changed?

Comment: Also, an exact upload script might help too :)

Comment: @AndriusNaruševičius the upload itself is fine, as with fewer rows, and sometimes will full row count, it completes successfully, the file itself is only 2M

Comment: I bet this is the PHP time-out limit.  Try using `set_time_limit(0);` to allow the script to run for as long as it wants.